# IntelliJ IDEA Debugger isn't working on a Grails Project

Tags: java, debugging, grails, intellij-idea

I can't debug my code in IntelliJ IDEA. When debug mode is active and running, but the breakpoints don't have that "v" checked that represents a valid and stoppable breakpoint.

See the image:

[image]

I really search on the web for an answer. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did it ever work?  I've had situations where intellij and grails got out of sync so debugging stopped working because intellij didn't "realize" that code.  A 'grails clean' fixes this pretty quickly.  What version of Intellij and Grails?

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Grails 2.3.0 and Intellij 12.1.5. The Clean command doesn't work too. I realized that project folder inside .grails/2.3.0/projects wasn't created.

Comment: This happened to me when I incorrectly set "debug: true" in the *compile* settings under "grails.project.fork".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I have tried all mentioned here without success.
The only helpful information is [here](http://www.groovy-code.com/2013/10/breakpoints-in-trouble-starring-grails.html).

In essence you should disable forked execution by adding the following to `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    run: false
]
```

Now debugging is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition v.12.1.6 just by ordinary Debug without Remote debugging.
Tested on Grails 2.3.1, Java 1.7.0_45, Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.3.4 and IntelliJ 13 as well +1. Working.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.3.8 and IntelliJ 13.1.3 as well +1 Working.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.4.0 and IntelliJ 13.1.3 - all working! I personally just commented the `run` and `test` lines that were in the aforementioned config map.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.4.2 and IntelliJ 13.1.3 - works by simply commenting out the runt / test lines as @atc mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Igors. Your solution solves this problem. Tested in Grails 2.3.4, 2.3.11 and 2.4.2 and IDEA 13.1.3.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.4.4 and IntelliJ 14.0.3 - works fine.

Comment: If anyone is having an issue getting this working, you may have made the same mistake as me: check whether you have an existing grails.project.fork block generated by the framework which should be updated with these lines instead of creating a new block.

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.4.4 and Intellij 14.1.2. Works fine. We actually used `grails.project.fork = false` but that did not work anymore when I upgraded from Intellij 14.1.1 to 14.1.2. Now I applied the solution to this question.

Comment: This will work but you should be aware what forking means. Good article [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-in-forked.html)

Comment: Tested on Grails 2.5.0 and IntelliJ 14.1.4 **not working**

Comment: Thank you from the future! This was really helpful. Tested on Grails 2.4.5 and Intellij 17.0.6

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

In idea choose ***Edit configurations*** from list next to 'run' button. Then add ***Remote***, choose your name and left default remote configuration settings. (port 5005 etc)

Run your app from console by using

```
grails run-app --debug-fork
```

In idea, choose your configuration from list and hit debug button when console display info:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The key was setting up a _new_ **Remote** debug config _instead of_ using the debug config that IntelliJ was automatically trying to insert for my grails app based on my app's code.

I used `grails -debug run-app` for my console command, then ran the new Remote config in debug mode from IntelliJ and it hooked right into my grails app.

Answer (score 8):

Since Grails 2.3, **forked execution** for several Grails commands (e.g. `run-app`, `test-app`) was [introduced](http://grails.io/post/43484836985/road-to-grails-2-3-forked-execution).
If you just debug a Grails application from IntelliJ IDEA, the `GrailsStarter` process will be started with debug options on. The output on the IDEA console will be:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:59935,suspend=y,server=n [...] /opt/idea-IU-133.330/lib/idea_rt.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter [...] run-app Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59935', transport: 'socket'
```

The application itself will be started in a separate process named `ForkedTomcatServer`. This is where your code runs and where your debugger should actually connect to.

To accomplish that, set `debug: true` in `BuildConfig.groovy` at the `run` configuration of `grails.project.fork`. Just run Grails now from IDEA (do not debug) and you will see the following line in the console when the application is ready to serve HTTP requests:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

This is where you want to direct a separate [remote run configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) to. As soon as your remote debugger connected, issue a HTTP request and debugging will work.

You can also **disable forked execution** for compile/test/run/war/console Grails commands entirely by setting the value associated with the command entry in `grails.project.fork` to `false`. But then you will lose the benefits for forked execution added in Grails 2.3.

Comment: Thank you, this got me in the right track. Ted Naleid provides a nice summary and details the pros and cons of disabling forked execution for debugging, with two useful alternatives: http://naleid.com/blog/2014/11/10/debugging-grails-forked-mode

Answer (score 6):

Debugging a grails (2.3+) application can be done in two ways.

**1. Simple solution: disable debug**

edit BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, fork ...
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, fork ...
```

to

```
grails.project.fork = [
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, fork ...
    run: false,
```

Pros:

- Simple to do (and get on with your development)

Cons:

- This removes the ability to perform runtime code replacement. This means that if you change code, it will no longer be picked up automatically and you will need to restart the application to see the changes. This can be very time consuming.

**2. Involved solution: debug forked runtime**

This is a somewhat more complex solution where you attach a debugger to a running grails application. It is described in more detail [in this blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.nl/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-in-forked.html).

After setup you have an extra run configuration that allows you to start up grails in forked mode, and yet another extra run configuration that allows you to debug that forked mode. The catch is that you are required to start both or it does not work.

Pros:

- You have both debugging and runtime code replacement
- This does not interfere with starting the application in normal mode. (i.e. you have extra options)

Cons:

- Setting up takes a little bit of time
- Starting up in debug mode requires is a more complex two step process (i.e. it takes longer)

**Considerations**

Solution 2 is mostly superior in the sense that it allows flexibility. I personally don't use debug a lot, so just start in normal mode. When I want to debug, I restart in debug mode.

Solution 1 is strictly better if you need to debug and also need to restart a lot. For instance when you are working on your domain classes or database setup in your BootStrap.groovy.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other answers work for me on Grails 3.x in 2016 w/ Intellij 15.0.4. This does work for me:

Start grails in intellij with this command:

```
run-app  --debug-jvm
```

The console should output:
"Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development"

Now you can add a new configuration of type, "Remote", in Intellij. Then  start it with its defaults.

And the new debug console window should write:
"Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'"

Done.

For those interested, the  reference to grails 3.x documentation for starting a debuggable server is at section 2.8, runningAndDebuggingAnApplication:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.x/guide/gettingStarted.html#runningAndDebuggingAnApplication

"There are several ways to execute the Application class, if you are using an IDE then you can simply right click on the class and run it directly from your IDE which will start your Grails application.
This is also useful for debugging since you can debug directly from the IDE without having to connect a remote debugger when using the run-app --debug-jvm command from the command line."

Important Note. When I tried the "simply right click on the class and run it directly from your IDE", the app did start. However, all requests I sent to my controller resulted in 500 errors with message: "Could not resolve view with name '/myendpoint' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'.

So, I reverted back to the instructions above.

Answer (score 4):

Did you see this article?  It details the how to step by step and got me past my problem.

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-in-forked.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simple matter with Grails 3 and Idea (2016.1). There's no need to edit any files anymore, as recommended in the other answers.

For some reason, the debug icon in the Idea toolbar is greyed out, so you just have to navigate to your application entry point (the class that has the static void main method that starts the application), click on one of the run arrows in the left-hand gutter and select the Debug option.

From the JetBrains docs:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/getting-started-with-grails-3.html

> Debugging Grails 3 Application
>
> IntelliJ IDEA lets you debug your Grails 3 application using
>   Application.groovy.
>
> In the Project tool window, open init directory and right-click the
>   Application.groovy From the drop-down list select Debug Grails:'name'
>   grails3_debug_app You can also use the editor to start the debugging
>   process.

Answer (score 1):

Just three guesses:

Try running `run-app`, not `run-war`, both should work, but may be `run-war` just isn't working.

Or: try debugging remotely from console:

`grails -debug run-app` and then connect with Remote Debug in Idea.

Or, the last resort: downgrading your project to previous Grails versions could work. Yes, this is really annoying.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with intellij latest with Grails 2.3.4 on Mac Os x Lion.

Then I tried Igors's advice and it is working without forked mode.

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    run: false
]
```

Please check for detail [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode)

if you want to debug forked mode you should check following blog post explainsvery well.

http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-forked-mode/

Answer (score 0):

This should not ever be the default configuration and only be left to the individual's choice. It's a freakin pain to do two configurations just get this thing running in debug mode in intellij. First you have to setup or modify the normal run configuration by adding  "--debug-fork" after run-app. Second, you have to configure remote debugging , while accepting all the defaults. Then you have to run the run configuration, and when that's running, you run the debug configuration. What a pain. I prefer totally doing away with running without the forked option while developing. Time is money and I don't have time to monkey around. See Mr.HAKI explanation on doing this. http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-forked-mode/

Comment: I think the answer would be more useful if you first gave the answer, then your commentary on why it is annoying. Perhaps leaving off most of the commentary as well.

Comment: No problem ... see my edited entry above: http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-forked-mode/   good luck.

Comment: Here is an update. I don't seem to be having this problem any more, but if it's not as important to you, I commented out portions of of the BuildConfig.groovy file under the conf directory that deals forking the JVM for optimizing memory when grails is running.

//uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate //classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

Answer (score 0):

1.terminal --> command : run-app --debug-jvm

console output:
grails> run-app --debug-jvm
| Running application...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005

NOTE: Change/Update port as per your client system

2. add debugger [ shoud be on port 5005 as default ] , "Remote JVM Debug", add new [ Intelli J setting ]

3.Once done , new debugger will be set [ step 2 ], run the the webapp on debug mode.

console output:
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport: 'socket'

4. Grails[intellij] has tomcat embedded at 8080, so hit "localhost:8080" and click on the controller [ where you added the toggele point ]

5.configuration is now connected - go ahead and explore your debugging skills to fix the issue :) :)

Comment: Use the formatting options available in Stackoverflow editor when posting an answer or a problem.