# unable to set breakpoint in grails 2.3.8 with intellij 13.1.2

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea

I am trying to set breakpoints in grails project(grails version:*2.3.8*, Intellij version:13.1.2), but all the breakpoint are ignored,but with the same environment,when the project's version is *2.1.0*, all is OK.
 Please let me know if anyone knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found following instructions on other site.

In IntelliJ, go to "Run / Edit Configurations", click + then "Remote" and name it whatever  you want (example "Grails Remote") then press ok.

Then from the command line do:

`grails run-app --debug-fork`

Attach your debugger by running your "Grails Remote" config. Done.

Another suggestion would be trying this in in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    run: false
]
```

Refer [Debugging App in Forked Mode blog](http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-forked-mode/)  and [grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode) for details

You can also try answers from [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247944/intellij-idea-debugger-isnt-working-on-a-grails-project)

Comment: --debug-fork helped me