# IntelliJ Idea 14 giving error on grails application debug

Tags: maven, grails, intellij-idea

I have started facing an issue with my Grails project after IntelliJ IDEA upgrade to 14.1.2 (from 14.1.1), all of a sudden my Grails project stopped working in debug mode. I believe a configuration change is required to enable debugging in newer version.

Here is the error that i am getting.

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.053 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-27T10:17:41+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/244M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'run-app --stacktrace' in plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3 among available goals generate-all, exec, package-plugin, maven-war, package, init, maven-functional-test, help, run-app-https, console, create-service, run-app, war, validate, set-version, test-app, clean, list-plugins, maven-compile, generate-controller, maven-clean, generate-views, install-templates, maven-test, create-domain-class, init-plugin, upgrade, config-directories, create-unit-test, create-controller, create-pom, validate-plugin, maven-grails-app-war, run-war, create-script, create-tag-lib, create-integration-test -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'run-app --stacktrace' in plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3 among available goals generate-all, exec, package-plugin, maven-war, package, init, maven-functional-test, help, run-app-https, console, create-service, run-app, war, validate, set-version, test-app, clean, list-plugins, maven-compile, generate-controller, maven-clean, generate-views, install-templates, maven-test, create-domain-class, init-plugin, upgrade, config-directories, create-unit-test, create-controller, create-pom, validate-plugin, maven-grails-app-war, run-war, create-script, create-tag-lib, create-integration-test
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: I see this exact same behavior.

Comment: have you included Grails SDK and Java JDK correctly .. also take a look at  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19778498/1850344

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that came into IntelliJ with version 14.1.2:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139568

You can fix it by upgrading to version 14.1.3 or newer.